# CSS Replace Image by accessing image URL

Tags: html, css, drupal

I have a banner which is scrolling multiple images using MD-Slider module (JCarousel). The website is responsive hence there would be 3 different layouts of any image inside the banner:

Normal Resolution:
[image: Normal Mode]

Layout for iPads and bigger tablets:
[image: Smaller Resolution - iPad]

Layout for Mobile:
[image: Mobile layout]

Currently I have used temporary images in the banner in the following fashion:

```
banner1.jpg
banner1-iPad.jpg
banner1-mobile.jpg
```

So, "banner1" is the key here. This is how my div looks for normal layout:

```
<div class="md-slide-item slide-1" data-timeout="8000" data-thumb="http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/TestWebsite/sites/default/files/styles/md_slider_1_thumb/public/banner1.jpg?itok=y4RT2g4r" style="height: 268px; left: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 1; display: block;">
    <div class="md-mainimg">
        <img class = "mdslider-img-tag" src="http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/TestWebsite/sites/default/files/banner1.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%; height: auto; top: -59.3653846153846px; left: 0px;">
    </div>
        <div class="md-objects" style="font-size: 99%;">
        </div>
</div>
```

I can use the class `mdslider-img-tag` to replace the image in CSS using some of the literature mentioned below:

1.https://css-tricks.com/replace-the-image-in-an-img-with-css/

2.http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/a_slick_new_image_swapping_technique_for_responsive_emails

However, my problem lies in getting the key "**banner1**" inside the css before appending **-iPad** or **-mobile** part of the text to same so that the right image for the layout is displayed.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you do it with background images + media queries?

Comment: As suggested by @sdcr above. You may use media queries instead. It's lighter that way. Hence it would be much easier for you too.

Comment: That is what I want to do, but as asked in the question, I would need the image name which is currently displayed by the slider so that I can append "-iPad" or "-mobile" to it so that the slider displays right image.

Comment: There is no way to do this with just css, unfortunately. A combination of the `attr()` and `url()` CSS functions would be ideal for this, but they aren't implemented in a way to solve this problem yet.

Comment: How would it be possible to address this problem then?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Interchange by Zurb, this works independent of Foundation themes but works best with them.

```
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html
```

While not a CSS solution I think this would actually be your best solution rather than creating a less than ideal CSS hack, CSS just isn't able to do what you want yet.